# Properly place MPMoviePlayerController inside UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, frame, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to provide video playback using MPMoviePlayerController.

I've added a UIView in a tableViewCell and added autolayout constraints to the UIView. Now, I want to add the MPMoviePlayerController to the UIView so it is the exact same size as the UIView and adopts all of the constraints.

My code is not working. (Unfortunately I can not post an image). My MPMoviePlayerController is not lined up correctly with the UIView; it is down and to the left. I am trying to get it to have the exact same frame and position as the UIView.

My code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var movieView: UIView! //connected via storyboard
var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    var videoURL:NSURL!
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
    moviePlayer.view.frame = movieView.bounds
    moviePlayer.view.center = movieView.center
    //moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
    //moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    //moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
    movieView.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I've tried a bunch of this, like using CGRectMake to set the frame of the moviePlayer, and setting the scaling mode as you can see commented in the code.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself.

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = movieView.bounds
moviePlayer.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(movieView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(movieView.bounds))
```